# Difference between Tizen CLI SDK Security Profile and Tizen Studio Certificate profile?

Tags: tizen, tizen-studio, tizen-sdk

Can anybody kindly guide me what is the difference between Tizen CLI SDK `Security Profile` and Tizen Studio `Certificate profile`?

Tizen CLI SDK does not have any option to create `Certificate profile` whereas they do have option to create `Security Profile` and in the same way Tizen Studio does not have option to create `Security Profile` whereas it has option to create `Certificate Profile` via Certificate manager

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, the terms **security profile** and **certificate profile** refer to the same thing and are used interchangeably:

- A **certificate**, refers to either an author certificate or a distributor certificate. An author certificate can be created with Tizen CLI's `certificate` command.
- A **security profile** or **certificate profile**, consists of an author certificate and one or more distributor certificates. A security profile can be created with Tizen CLI's `security-profiles add` command.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying, it seems like the case. But, I am unable to understand why Samsung created 2 different terminologies for the same thing and never mentioned anywhere that both are same thing. This is confusing.

Comment: It's confusing for me too and I don't have any idea why. Tizen SDK always tends to be messy and undocumented. :(